# Tomcat Response API and getCommitTime() function

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, network-programming, tomcat8

In the tomcat documentation what is the usage of the method [getCommitTime()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/Response.html#getCommitTime())?
It just says:

> Return the time the response was committed (based on
> System.currentTimeMillis).

but what does that mean and when is this method used?